# How to add greater then or less then query parameter in retrofit call?

Tags: android, retrofit2

How to make api call for below url using Retrofit.

```
BASE_URL?time>1458034997.
```

Have tried with

```
@GET("")
Call<Model> getModel(@Query("time") int time);
```

Unable to change it to greater then or less then ,it's always coming as equals.

Comment: do it backend side. `time=1458034997` and backend side check starting from time onwards

Comment: This should not be possible by url design. Query parameters are `KEY=VALUE`, you must have an `=`. You could do something like `time=>1455766768`

Comment: @Blackbelt can we do this without modification in backend side?Any work around would be better.Like putting complete URL dynamically in Call.

Comment: @GET
Call<Model> getModel(@Url String url); where url is BASE_URL?time>1458034997. It's look like this is the option can be used ,if we don't have access to modify backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@QueryName`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/QueryName.html) annotation.

You'll need to create the string to pass to retrofit before you call `getModel()`

```java
@GET("")
Call<Model> getModel(@QueryName String time);

getModel("time>1458034997.");

// yields BASE_URL/?time>1458034997.
```